# How to avoid changes to field data type in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, nosql

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm starting a new project with Spring Data MongoDB.

I created a simple model POJO and I inserted some documents into `products` collection:

```
@Document(collection="products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    // ...
}
```

In my DB field types are mapped correctly:

- `name` to `String`,
- `price` to `Double`,
- `quantity` to `Int32`

But making some test i tried to increment `quantity` field via `$inc` modifier:

```
db.products.update({"name" : "A product"}, {"$inc" : {"quantity" : 1}});
```

and now `quantity` field type is changed to `Double`.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I will give that. Simple reproduce `db,test.insert({ "a": NumberLong("1") }); db.test.update({ "a": 1 },{ "$inc": { "a": 1 } })`. Now a Double.

Comment: @NeilLunn so... the lesson is: "don't use $inc"? :)

Comment: Possibly so.( ROFL ) but not the preferred "answer" here. I would like to see a reasonable response as to why this is so ( generic obvious aside ) and why more strict type checking cannot be done. I am notoriously lazy at grepping code that is not mine.

Comment: That said though, this is a correct result: `db,test.insert({ "a": NumberLong("1") }); db.test.update({ "a": 1 },{ "$inc": { "a": NumberLong("1") } })`. And that retains the same type. So what I said about the "generic obvious" stands because adding `1` and `1.25` cannot result in an integer type of any description.for "obvious" reasons. But should It be so? Well maybe. I just waited for the sound of tumbleweeds to point out what anyone with a reasonable knowledge should have seen immediately. No offence to the poster of a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Neil Lunn** comment, I realized that a way to keep the same data type for my `quantity` field is to explicitly specify the type of the increment amount.

In this case I have an `Int32` so I can use this code to update it:

```
db.products.update({"name" : "A product"}, {"$inc" : {"quantity" : NumberInt(1)}});
```